# Conditional Regex not working as expected

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a conditional Regex to achieve the following:

```
If the word "apple" or "orange" is present within a string:
   there must be at least 2 occurrences of the word "HORSE" (upper-case)
else 
   there must be at least 1 occurrence of the word "HORSE" (upper-case)
```

What I wrote so far:

`(?(?=((apple|orange).*))(HORSE.*){2}|(HORSE.*){1})`

I was expecting this Regex to work as I'm following the pattern `(?(?=regex)then|else)`.

However, it looks like `(HORSE.*){1}` is always evaluated instead. Why?

https://regex101.com/r/V5s8hV/1

Comment: This is sufficiently complex enough to seriously consider implementing outside of RegExp, in a language with better ability to support the logic you wish to implement.

Comment: Interesting. I thought this was still possible using a Regex. Thanks

Comment: @esqew It is possible in regex, though bloated, and if this had to be done from a programming language like Java or Python, I would opt to use helper functions rather than a pure regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional is nice for checking a condition in one place and use outcome in another.

```
^(?=(?:.*?\b(apple|orange)\b)?)(.*?\bHORSE\b)(?(1)(?2))
```

- The condition is *[group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) one* inside an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `(?:` [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) `)`
- In the *second group* the part until `HORSE` which we always need gets matched
- `(?(1)(?2))` conditional if *first group* succeeded, require *group two pattern* [again](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html)

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nIQ99O/1) (more explanation on the right side)

---

The way you planned it does work as well, but needs refactoring e.g. [that regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dGe4hN/1).

```
^(?(?=.*?\b(?:apple|orange)\b)(?:.*?\bHORSE\b){2}|.*?\bHORSE\b)
```

---

Or another way without conditional and a negative lookahead like [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1UduE1/1).

```
^(?:(?!.*?\b(?:apple|orange)\b).*?\bHORSE\b|(?:.*?\bHORSE\b){2})
```

---

FYI: To get full string in the output, just attach `.*` at the end. Further to mention, `{1}` is redundant. Used a [lazy quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) (as few as possible) in the [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)-parts of all variants for improving efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use lookaheads to assert the number of occurrences of the word `HORSE`:

```
^((?=.*\bHORSE\b.*\bHORSE\b).*\b(?:apple|orange)\b.*|(?=.*\bHORSE\b)(?!.*\b(?:apple|orange)\b).*)$
```

### Demo

Explanation:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(` match either of

  - `(?=.*\bHORSE\b.*\bHORSE\b)` assert that `HORSE` appears at least twice
  - `.*` match any content
  - `\b(?:apple|orange)\b` match `apple` or `orange`
  - `.*` match any content
  - `|` OR
  - `(?=.*\bHORSE\b)` assert that `HORSE` appears at least once
  - `(?!.*\b(?:apple|orange)\b)` but `apple` and `orange` do not occur
  - `.*` match any content
- `)` close alternation
- `$` end of the string

Comment: You could shorten it by using `(?=(?:.*\bHORSE\b){2})`